# What is the path from a model to the database?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a project created from the ASP.NET Core Web Application template in VS. When run, the project creates a database to support the Identity package.

The Identity package is a Razor Class Library. I have scaffolded it and the models can be seen. The models are sub-classed from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageModel`.

I am tracing the code to try and get a better understanding of how it all works. I am trying to find the path from the models to the physical database.

In the file `appsettings.json`, I see the connection string `DefaultConnection` pointing to the physical database.

In `startup.cs`, I see a reference to the connection string `DefaultConnection`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

After this, I lost the trail. I can't find the link from a model in code to a table in the database. What is the code needed to perform a query like `select * from AspNetUsers`?

Comment: There is the _ApplicationDbContext_ that you did configure with the _DefaultConnection_ ConnectionString. What you need is an instance of that context. You get it from dependency injection, passed to the constructor of the class where you want to use it. With that instance at hand you have access to the users. (e.g. _db.AspNetUsers.ToList()_) would then produce something similar to _select * from aspnetusers_)

Comment: I very much recommend the 101 videos on channel9 and the (getting started) doc on https://learn.microsoft.com

Comment: In the above `services.AddDbContext` method, how can the `ApplicationDbContext` that is so added be referenced and accessed elsewhere in my code?

Comment: To understand this, you need to understand dependency injection (DI) and inversion of control (IC). The above code adds the context to the DI container. You can then inject it into any class you like. DI takes care of instantiating and much more. The template project makes use of DI everywhere and it is a very crucial concept within asp.net core and in programming in general. You need to understand this and you wont by just looking at the template project. So I repeat myself - read the docs and/or watch introductory videos

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel Schmid suggested , you should firstly learn the [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

ASP.NET Core has an excellent Dependency Injection feature through which this framework provides you with an object of any class that you want. So you don’t have to manually create the class object in your code.

EF Core supports using `DbContext` with a dependency injection container. Your `DbContext` type can be added to the service container by using the `AddDbContext<TContext>` method.

Then you can use the instance like :

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

or using ServiceProvider directly, less common :

```
using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
{
    // do stuff
}

var options = serviceProvider.GetService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>();
```

And get users by directly querying the database :

```
var users = _context.Users.ToList();
```

Please also read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext) .